# In a Visual Studio + Remote Xamarin build server setup, can an iOS be deployed locally, without the App Store, and without a mac physically present?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

TLDR; In a Visual Studio + Xamarin build server setup-which computer does an iOS device physically connect to when deploying locally. The App store is not an option. So is it the PC or the Mac? I have found a lot of set up and configuration instructions, but this simple point overlooked in everything I’ve found so far.

I have been attempting to figure out if I can use a service such as macincloud.com for my purposes. If I was simply deploying to the App Store it seems pretty straight forward. However, I do not want to deploy to the app store in fact I can’t as a requirement of this project I’m working on. We do not have a mac and do not otherwise need one and do not foresee needed one again for anything else anytime soon.

If I have a physical mac it seems easy enough to deploy locally, but with a remote machine can I install an iOS app from a remote mac through a local windows machine running Visual Studio? I’ve only been able to find examples where people either have physical access to both machines, control of their network (Xamarin Live Player, I am uncertain at this point if I am authorized to connect a new device to the network as this requires both your IDE and a device to be on the same network by my understanding), or they are deploying to the App Store(which understanding is straight forward if you are allowed to do this).

Having never developed for iOS before I’m not sure if the Visual Studio with a Xamarin build server requires that my iOS device requires a physical connection to the mac to be deployed on a local device.

Comment: if your build server produces an IPA file you can use ad-hoc deployment to distribute it.  Services like HockeyApp/App Center make this easier, but it is possible to just download and install an ad-hoc IPA through the device's browser

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can RDP into the mac so in theory I should be able to access this file, even if its not on my local machine.  I'll check out HockeyApp/App Center and see if that is something that will work out. It seems like something that has the net effect of what I'm after.